# How to call combobox loaded event on winload

Tags: c#, wpf, events, combobox

I have a loaded event of combobox placed in each datagrid row.Event is as following.

```
   private void show(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

   {

           ComboBox cmb = null;

            if (sender is ComboBox)
            {
                cmb = (sender as ComboBox);

            }

            for (var vis = sender as Visual; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as Visual)
                if (vis is DataGridRow)
                {
                    var row = (DataGridRow)vis;
                    break;


                }
              cmb.items.add("1","2","3");

         }
```

Now I want to call it at winload or any button event as method. how it is possible.

Comment: Wow. Super confusing code here. And please rewrite your question. *Now I want to call it at winload or any button event as method* - What do you mean with that?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but what you're saying is not possible. You cannot find a combobox loaded event from somewhere, since it is not under your control.

It is fired internally when the combobox is loaded. Hence you get the `sender` as combobox.

If your purpose is simply adding values to the combobox consider binding the data template of your data grid to some source and bind the combobox source to some collection. Doing that will add the items initially to the combobox while the application is loaded and you could change the values accordingly while the application is running by changing the bound sources of combobox in the datatemplate.